# Urlconnection.setProperty("Authorization", authHeader) not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, http

I am testing some API's of a platform using jbehave. The API's are secured and thereby need authorization. The type of authorization is Bearer. When i tried to authorize the API request like below, I got a status code of 401 printed out. Don't understand where i am going wrong. Can someone help me please. My authHeader below is - `"Bearer " + new String("token recieved")`.

```java
public class hello {

    static WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(
                    wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort());

    static CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    static String authHeader = "Bearer " + new String("token");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        wireMockServer.start();
        URL url = new URL("https://sandbox.predera.com/aiq/api/projects");
        URLConnection urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(String.valueOf(url));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        int n = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        wireMockServer.stop();
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information about the external API you are testing. First, I think a specific token is required, not the string "token", but I can't say more without API documentation.

Comment: By "token" i mean the authorization token that i recieved like: "BaNnk0NElmdllGNDZqVDlvRG5RZWxoeUg4d1JjMVwvWkdBND0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhMGNhZjMyYy0zY2Q0LTQyNzAtYmQ4NC1kOWI4N2"

Comment: Did you tried do the same with other tools, like postman? It is probably a problem with a specific API, I am asking for documentation again.

Comment: Not everyone can access the API documentation, you need to have access to it. And, yes it works on postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pointless as you set Authorization header for this given connection, and then invoke `httpClient` that internally opens separate connection with no header applied:

```java
URLConnection urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
```

One of the solutions:

```java
HttpUriRequest httpGet = RequestBuilder.get()
  .setUri("https://sandbox.predera.com/aiq/api/projects")
  .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
  .build();

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! This worked! But i did not understand your explanation that well. Can you explain again a little more in depth and also direct me to some online resources on these topics to understand better. Thanks again! I really appreciate it

Comment: @abdv19 it's hard to improve my explanation since you didn't clarify what exactly is unclear in the current. URL is just a string representing web (in your case) resource, not a globally locked link between the resource and your application, so you can established hundreds of independent connections to the same resource identified by single URL within same application. Therefore when you open connection `A` and apply some modifications (add header) to it they don't affect connection `B` which is opened later in your other code unless you reuse same connection.

Comment: Oh right got! But where is my second connection being opened?

Comment: @abdv19 somewhere inside HttpClient